# VBA error 400 looping through a range (36378 rows)

Tags: excel, vba

i have a workbook with two sheets, once holds a drop-down list of names, in the other sheet there's a huge table with 36378 rows, there are two columns in particular i need, one that holds the names and one the Id.

I need to take the name from the first sheet, loop through the name column in the second sheet, find the row and go to the column that holds the Ids.

I wrote the following code, where i used to ranges, one to store names and the other one Ids, however when i loop it gives me a 400 error, i dont know if because the file is too huge, or it's something else.

Here is the code below :

```
Sub FindUCPId()

Dim ucp, ucpId As String
ucpId = 0

Worksheets(1).Activate
ucp = Range("B4").Value

Dim rngUCP, rngUCPId As Range


Worksheets(2).Activate
Set rngUCP = Range(Range("BI1"), Range("BI1").End(xlDown))
Set rngUCPId = Range(Range("BG1"), Range("BG1").End(xlDown))

Dim i As Variant
i = 0

While (rngUCP.Cells(i, 1) <> ucp) And (rngUCP.Cells(i, 1) <> "")
   i = i + 1
Wend

MsgBox (ucpId)
End Sub
```

Thanks !

Comment: Is there a reason you define `i` as a `Variant` instead of a `Long`? And do you realize that `ucp` is being defined as a `Variant` and not a `String` like you may think?

Comment: Please read up on the correct use of Dim.

Comment: on your 1st loop iteration, I don't think the range rngUPC.Cells(0,1) is valid.  Why are you starting at 0 and not 1?  Also upcID will always be 0. Last bit, you have ucpID as a String but set it as a number.  "0" (string version) and 0 (numeric you have it set to) are two different things.

Comment: When you get the error, enter debugging mode and tell us which line fails. Or run it in debugging mode directly.

Comment: Also, you can use the `.Find` method instead of using the loop. Generally speaking, do you use this workbook for a single lookup, or do you make multiple lookups in a session? How often does the sheet with 36k rows change?

Comment: @eventHandler I ran the debugger it stops on the while line, it gives me error 1004.

Comment: @braX I changed i to Long, as for for ucp, i dont know why it isn't declared as a string?

Comment: @sous2817 ucpId it was a mistake, the value of it (after the loop), would be : ucpId = rngUCPId.Cells(i, 0).

Comment: @freeflow i did find that Dim is to declare variables? please any enlightnement is welcomed, i am indeed new to vba, been using it on small projects for three weeks now, and this is my first one on a large file, and this is only the first step.

Comment: `Dim ucp, ucpId As String` means `Dim ucp As Variant, ucpId As String` - you probably wanted `Dim ucp as String, ucpId As String`

Comment: also i read in many topics that the issue could be related to activating the worksheets? but i am writing my code on thisworkbook and not on single sheet

Comment: okay it just worked, i had to change the i to =1 and not 0, the rangecountrows starts from 1, my bad.

thank you all for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: In the VBA IDE put your cursor on the Word DIm and Press F1.  This will bring up the MS Help page on DIm.